# node js installation on Apache HTTP server (centOS)

Tags: node.js, apache

I'm working at a project in school that includes Apache server.
All i need to do right now to start working with the server is create An index file (html, ph) at my folder on the server (inside the public_html) and the server will return that page.

but the thing is that I want to write the server with nodejs.
I have already manage to install node on the server but I know how to ignore the Apache server and start working with node.

I read about that and I saw that i need to start node on a different port? or use proxy?
but I really don't know that much about servers.

Comment: Yeah, u can just bind nodejs to a different port in your script or either stop Apache and run it through port 80 (default) or you can go down the long trip and play with proxies

Comment: @ryanc1256 you know how to do that?

Comment: what way do you want to go? Do Apache proxies or just just nodejs on port 80

Answer (score 1):

You can use apache as proxy for nodejs https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html.

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```

Or, if you want to run the nodejs not from root directory of server

```
ProxyPass /mynodejsproject http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse /mynodejsproject http://localhost:3000/
```

For example, nodejs application listens on 3000 port, apache on 80 port, and it proxies requests to nodejs application.

But i recommend you to use nginx as proxy for nodejs application, this is the config i used in my projects https://github.com/vodolaz095/hunt/blob/master/examples/serverConfigsExamples/nginx.conf

Comment: Also just a tip if you go down this way and you use websockets you also have to do ProxyPass for websockets as well, but i think in new Apache versions they have fixed it so that you can proxyPass it, but yeah just have a look into it, if your having problems with websockets

Answer (score 0):

`service apache2 stop`  Stops your apache server (It works on 80 port default)

Also there is a good tool for nodejs ,you will able to manage your nodeJS server(you can give 80 port now) like services with [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) on nodeJS.(I assumed you know how to creating your nodejs http server)

Comment: Hey the thing is that because it a school server wont i stop like that the server for every one else? and BTW service is unknown command :\

Comment: probably you can stop it by `systemctl stop apache` - if it is rpm based repo

Comment: Then you will specify your port, here is a code snippets in nodejs doc.http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server